# Backup jenkins build job configuration to SVN

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I need to add jenkins build job configurations to SVN. Is there a plugin to do this? Can we automate build job configuration backup in jenkins?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at this: [SCM Sync configuration plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/SCM+Sync+configuration+plugin)
and this: [keeping-your-configuration-and-data-subversion](http://jenkins-ci.org/content/keeping-your-configuration-and-data-subversion)

Good starting points.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Huge **WARNING** for the SCM Sync plugin. If you are using Subversion for storing the configuration, it will break on job rename... and not just for that job, but for the whole installation.

Comment: Also, 0.0.9 version of the plugin cannot pickup credentials from subversion plugin version 2+. So, I can tell that SCM Sync plugin should not be used in production.